# glmmadmb error: function maximizer failed (couldn't find STD file)

Tags: r, poisson

I am trying to run a glmmadmb model with standardized abundance as the response with a random effect of region plus fixed effects of julian day and elevation with a poisson distribution and zero inflation. My code is as follows:

```
m17.5<-glmmadmb(stdabund~kmelev+(1|region)+julian, data=breed, zeroInflation=TRUE,family="poisson")
```

I noticed that there was a similiar thread however this is using a different distribution and is not using MCMC, but I am getting the same error:

> Error in glmmadmb(stdabund ~ kmelev + (1 | region) + julian, data = breed,  : 
>     The function maximizer failed (couldn't find STD file) Troubleshooting steps include (1) run with 'save.dir' set and inspect output files; (2) change run parameters: see '?admbControl'

Comment: What happened when you followed the troubleshooting steps outlined in the error?

Comment: After following the troubleshooting steps I believe I need to change the number of separable calls to 50,000 becuase the dimensions of my dataframe is approx 46,000 by 10. Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: a little more information please.  Have you centered and scaled your predictors yet?  This is usually the lowest-hanging fruit. Does the model work without zero-inflation?  Can you show us the results of `summary(breed)`?  Have you looked at some plots of your data?

Comment: I after I bit of research I found that adding the command extra.args= -ndi 60000 was all I needed. Thanks for the Help!